# Does the Minhag to say Barchi Nafshi after Shabbat Mincha in winter include Shabbat Chanuka

Tags: shabbat, minhag, tehilim-psalms

Does the minhag (Ashkenazi Nusach Sfard) to say Barchi Nafshi after Shabbat Mincha in winter include Shabbat Chanuka? Are there any Shabbatot that the minhag is not to say Barchi Nafshi? According to [this](https://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=336) source it seems that Shabbat Chanuka is not taken into account to the number of Shabbatot in which we supposed to say Barchi Nafshi.